# Java Bug (?): Argument getName() changes when passing parameters

Tags: java

I'm trying to add scopes to my dependency injection package. So I figured I'd define a *Scope* like this:

```
public interface Scope {

    <T> T apply(T type);

    <T> T resolve(Class<T> type);

}
```

And then make an enumeration implementing that interface like this:

```
public enum Scopes implements Scope {

    DEFAULT,

    SINGLETON {

        private final Map<String, Object> singletons = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        @Override
        public <T> T apply(T object) {
            if (!singletons.containsKey(object.getClass().getName())) {
                singletons.put(object.getClass().getName(), object);
                System.out.println("Applied for: " + object.getClass().getName());
            }
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> T resolve(Class<T> type) {
            Object object = singletons.get(type.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("Resolved for: " + type.getClass().getName());
            return object == null ? null : (T) object;
        }

    };

    @Override
    public <T> T apply(T object) {
        return object;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T resolve(Class<T> type) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

However, when using code such as this:

```
System.out.println("Real type: " + type.getName());
T result = scope.resolve(type);
```

The resolved for output becomes *java.lang.Class* for some strange reason yet the real type outputs correctly.

Comment: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Why the resolved type becomes _java.lang.Class_ rather than what I pass in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's no <s>moon</s>bug.

> The resolved for output becomes java.lang.Class for some strange reason yet the real type outputs correctly.

Because `Class#getName()` is `java.lang.Class` when `this` is a `Class<Class>`, and the class of `type` is always `Class` – because that's what you've defined `type`'s class as in the method signature!

You already *have* a `Class` instance (`type`, remember?) so remove the extra `getClass()` call. Change this line:

```
System.out.println("Resolved for: " + type.getClass().getName());
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("Resolved for: " + type.getName());
```